# Using selenium java I want to automate a survey page. The problem arises with a question with several sub-questions

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automation, cucumber

Using selenium java I want to automate a survey page. Every question has the same HTML code. The problem arises with a question with several sub-questions. Each subquestion has the same HTML code.

What I tried to do?
I tried to rely on "name" and "value". After completion, the "Continue" button is displayed
Locators

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//input[@name='select-12'][0]")
    WebElement question10;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//input[@name='select-12'][1]")
    WebElement question10a;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//input[@name='select-12'][2]")
    WebElement question10b;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//input[@name='select-12'][3]")
    WebElement question10c;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//input[@name='select-12'][4]")
    WebElement question10d;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//input[@name='select-12'][5]")
    WebElement question10e;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//input[@name='select-12'][6]")
    WebElement question10f;


    //executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", question10);
//        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
//        js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,200)", "");
        //executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", question10a);
        executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", question10b);
        executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", question10c);
        executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", question10d);
        executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", question10e);
        executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", question10f);
        executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", question11);
        disclaimer.click();
        continua.click();
```

Page HTML Code:
[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eql31.png)

The questioned image:
[Question image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCAuj.png)

How I can complete the question?

Comment: Can you share that html in text format here or even Page url if it's public

Comment: <label><img class="icon" style="display: none;"> <input type="radio" name="select-12" value="0">     0    </label> <label><img class="icon" style="display: none;"> <input type="radio" name="select-12" value="0">     0    </label>

Comment: That's not enough HTML, Page URL can you share ?

Comment: All sub-questions are identical

Comment: No I see, there is a, b, c, d, e, f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question heading is different such as :

```
a. Activitati cotidiene si activitati ce tin de locul tau de munca
```

or

```
b. Hobiuri si activitati sportive
```

based on heading we can differentiate xpath (The below xpath is for first question):

```
//strong[contains(text(), 'a.')]/../descendant::input[@value='0']/..
```

for second or 3rd question all you have to do is to change the question heading in place of `a.` to that particular question heading like `b.`  and so on..

and if you wanna click on 0, then leave this as it is `input[@value='0']` but in case if you want to do click on `1, 2, 3,` or any other number, you would have to change the number here :

```
input[@value='1']
```

or

```
input[@value='2']
```

and so on..

Comment: can it also be adapted for disclaimer?

Comment: What do you mean for disclaimer ?

Comment: I try to understand the locators rules and logic.

Comment: Did it work ? Do you need any more help on this ?

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't matter which option you select, you could do a `List<WebElement>` with the css locator '`.sub-question .answers:nth-child(6) input`' and select all items in a loop (the exemple is for selecting answer option '4' for each sub-question, you can change it as you want)

```
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;

import java.util.List;

public class QuestionTenPage {
    WebDriver driver;

    @FindBy(css = ".sub-question .answers:nth-child(6) input")
    private List<WebElement> lastAnswerForSubQuestions;

    public void checkAllSubQuestions() {
        lastAnswerForSubQuestions.forEach(radio -> ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", radio));
    }
}
```